# Chroot cross-compile undefined symbols

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, gcc, chroot

I'm trying to "cross-compile" application from Ubuntu 14.04 to Debian Wheezy 7.9 (non-compatible libc version between the two). I've setup the chroot environment where I've installed the debian Wheezy. I'm using code blocks for compilation on Ubuntu. I've setup the project so I'm using only stuff from the chroot environment (that is gcc, libc, etc.). I'm also using `-nodefaultlibs` and linking everything by the hand. But even then I've got unresolved symbols and don't know where they come from.

```
/var/chroot/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/libgcc_s.so: undefined reference to `memcpy@GLIBC_2.14'
/var/chroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so: undefined reference to `__clock_getres@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/var/chroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so: undefined reference to `__pthread_get_minstack@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/var/chroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so: undefined reference to `__clock_gettime@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/var/chroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so: undefined reference to `__clock_nanosleep@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/var/chroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so: undefined reference to `__clock_getcpuclockid@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/var/chroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so: undefined reference to `__clock_settime@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
```

/var/chroot/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/libgcc_s.so doesn't haven't reference to 2.14 (have looked through objdump)

Here is my command line:

```
g++-4.7 -L../Debug
-L../dependencies/lib/debug
-L/var/chroot/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7
-L/var/chroot/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
-L/var/chroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
-L/var/chroot/usr/lib
-o ../Debug/xxx obj/Debug/src/xxx.o
-nostdlib -Wl,-t
 /var/chroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o
 /var/chroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o
 /var/chroot/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/crtbegin.o
 -lboost_system-gcc47-mt-d-1_55
 -lboost_filesystem-gcc47-mt-d-1_55
 -lboost_program_options-gcc47-mt-d-1_55
 -lboost_thread-gcc47-mt-d-1_55
 -l:libpthread-2.13.so
 -lxxxD
 -l:libcrypto++.a
 -lgcc_s
 -lstdc++
 -lrt
 -lm
 -l:libc.so.6
 -l:libgcc.a
 -l:libc_nonshared.a
 -l:ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
 /var/chroot/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/crtend.o
 /var/chroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
```

The boost libraries are compiled in chroot-ed environment and made as static libs. I've set the gcc/ld flag to print all the linked stuff by full path and indeed everything is loaded from the chroot.

Anybody know what could be wrong? Is the path I've chosen feasible?

Comment: uh... why do you use codeblocks for that and don't you simply chroot and use make in you evironment? Oo
I mean, if you were talking about cross-compile to windows or ARM or 64/32, ok, but what you want seems just to compile to another distrib with other lib versions...

Comment: Because the project is already set-up in code blocks and want to be able to debug it there if some problem occurs. But unfortunately I cannot export the makefile from the codeblocks and I really don't know how to write from scratch (and it would be time consuming I think).

Comment: The ugly hack which works it to compile all the object files with codeblocks (on host) and run the link command only in the chroot environment.

Comment: don't... ever... write a makefile yourself (except for VERY small and personal projects)... there are tools for this purpose like the great cmake.
Well you want to debug a cross-compiled application ? I hope you know you can't just do it directly : you have to go with a remote debugger. (gdb works well with that, but I don't know how C::B manage it). I suggest you to document yourself a bit about compilation and linux before trying to do that kind of thing. As a rule : never try to cross-compile when you can compile native (except if you have a good reason like on a "embedded and slow chip"

Comment: Anyway, it seems like either you forgot a libraries, either you are using the version lib is too low for your project or one of its dependencies

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but this question isn't about the make systems. The code block environment is the one I'm using and I don't want to change that. As to the errors, yes I know what they mean, but I would like to know when is this missing dependency generated. It could be, that I'm using the gcc 4.7 from the host, not from the chroot and that it is somehow embedding the functions.

Comment: try `ldd <path to your chroot>[/usr]/lib/librt.so` and check if you have all the deps. But you should compile chrooted... C::B should work from command-line anyway, so try to compile in the chroot environment, or even better : boot on your debian, install C::B then compile from command line (I guess you have no GUI yet)

Comment: ldd won't help here. Maybe I have badly formulated the question. The problem isn't a missing symbol as a such, but that linker (or gcc) is passing wrong libraries (or to be precise, is linking to the functions that are in the newer versions of the libc). Yes, you're right I have no GUI there. Running the CB in the console is a good suggestion, that could solve it. I'll need to try it. Thanks.